# Print data with bbcode from database to HTML

Tags: php, html, database, parsing, bbcode

I've got a textarea form, with BBcode support, the text written on the form is saved on my database using PHP, everything works fine. 
But when I try to print the data from my database I get this:
[b]hello[/b]

instead of this:

**hello**

this is the way I print from database:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BlogData ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$content = $row['content'];

echo nl2br($content);
```

what should I do to see my text like I actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$regex = array(
  '/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is' => '<b>$1</b>',
  '/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/is' => '<i>$1</i>',
  '/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/is' => '<u>$1</u>',
  '/\[s\](.*?)\[\/s\]/is' => '<strike>$1</strike>',
  '/\[sup\](.*?)\[\/sup\]/is' => '<sup>$1</sup>',
  '/\[sub\](.*?)\[\/sub\]/is' => '<sub>$1</sub>',
  '/\[color=#([0-9A-F]{6})\](.*?)\[\/color\]/is' => '<font color="#$1">$2</font>',
  '/\[left\](.*?)\[\/left\]/is' => '<p style="text-align:left">$1</p>',
  '/\[center\](.*?)\[\/center\]/is' => '<p style="text-align:center">$1</p>',
  '/\[right\](.*?)\[\/right\]/is' => '<p style="text-align:right">$1</p>',
  '/\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is' => '<div class="quote"><span>$1</span></div>'
  );
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BlogData ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$content = preg_replace(array_keys($regex), array_values($regex), $row['content']);

echo nl2br($content);
}
```

Comment: works flawlessly, do you know somewhere I can just copy/paste all the BBcodes? I'll try to do some by my self, but if u know, please tell me!